# How to Increase Font of Menu bar in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

Does anyone know how to increase the Font of Menu bar & project explorer in Eclipse? I already know how to increase the code font.

[image]

Comment: All available font settings can be found under Window -> Preferences (then use search box, e.g. type "font" there). However, there're no settings you want. These fonts are the system ones. Looks like you're on Windows, so try this solutions: https://superuser.com/questions/951199/windows-10-system-font-size-change

Comment: I'm not trying to Change font in all windows menus. Just the application IDE Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

FOR ECLIPSE OXYGEN :
[eclipse](/questions/tagged/eclipse)

Step : 1
Go tho eclipse folder

Step : 2
cd /eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.ui.themes_1.2.0.v20160718-0743/css/e4_basestyle.css

Step : 3
open in any editor the file **e4_basestyle.css** and add following lines

```
* {font-size: 14;
}
```

Step : 4 
Save the file **e4_basestyle.css**

Step : 5
Restart the eclipse

Comment: I see no such file. Eclipse 2021-12.

Comment: it may have been moved to: /d/dev/java-2022-03/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.theme - but this folder is empty.

Answer (score 0):

r-click desktop
display
Scale and Layout
Change the size of text, apps, and other items

Not ideal, but it works

Comment: This is a non-answer. I see this "increase system DPI/system font" answer all the time for this kind of question, but this has significant consequences (affecting other applications that are already big) on Windows.